# How to override xml under config directory to hide SonataMediaBundle and Classification setting from dashboard

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have installed SonataMediaBundle and SonataClassification Bundle with SonataAdminBundle

Media Library and Classification Library tables appear automatically in admin dashboard.

[image]

However, I would like to remove this two panes.

Now, I have found these settings are written in vendor/sonata-project/classification-bundle/Resources/config/admin.xml

I guess this file is related though, this is in vendor directory.

I have my original bundle `ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle` to override `SonataClassificationBundle`

I can override files in controller, however in Resources/config directory??

How can I override this file and remove from dashboard??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="sonata.classification.admin.category" class="%sonata.classification.admin.category.class%">
            <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="sonata_classification" label="label_categories" label_catalogue="%sonata.classification.admin.category.translation_domain%" label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore"/>
            <argument/>
            <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.category.entity%</argument>
            <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.category.controller%</argument>
            <argument type="service" id="sonata.classification.manager.context"/>
            <call method="setTranslationDomain">
                <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.category.translation_domain%</argument>
            </call>
            <call method="setTemplates">
                <argument type="collection">
                    <argument key="list">SonataClassificationBundle:CategoryAdmin:list.html.twig</argument>
                    <argument key="tree">SonataClassificationBundle:CategoryAdmin:tree.html.twig</argument>
                </argument>
            </call>
        </service>
        <service id="sonata.classification.admin.tag" class="%sonata.classification.admin.tag.class%">
            <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="sonata_classification" label="label_tags" label_catalogue="%sonata.classification.admin.tag.translation_domain%" label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore"/>
            <argument/>
            <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.tag.entity%</argument>
            <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.tag.controller%</argument>
            <argument type="service" id="sonata.classification.manager.context"/>
            <call method="setTranslationDomain">
                <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.tag.translation_domain%</argument>
            </call>
        </service>
        <service id="sonata.classification.admin.collection" class="%sonata.classification.admin.collection.class%">
            <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="sonata_classification" label="label_collections" label_catalogue="%sonata.classification.admin.collection.translation_domain%" label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore"/>
            <argument/>
            <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.collection.entity%</argument>
            <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.collection.controller%</argument>
            <argument type="service" id="sonata.classification.manager.context"/>
            <call method="setTranslationDomain">
                <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.collection.translation_domain%</argument>
            </call>
        </service>
        <service id="sonata.classification.admin.context" class="%sonata.classification.admin.context.class%">
            <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="sonata_classification" label="label_contexts" label_catalogue="%sonata.classification.admin.context.translation_domain%" label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore"/>
            <argument/>
            <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.context.entity%</argument>
            <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.context.controller%</argument>
            <call method="setTranslationDomain">
                <argument>%sonata.classification.admin.context.translation_domain%</argument>
            </call>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```